# Xuggle android to android video streaming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xuggle

I am trying to use Xuggle ( with Eclipse in Win7 ) and the target is android device, better said, stream video from one android device to another ( locally stored video on one android device ).

First question : Xuggle web page was a bit confusing for me. I was unable to understand if I should download jar file for windows when it goes to android device, or some linux based ? No android version there. Also many of the links are dead, or those small tutorials link to dead pages ( or links were removed ). **Which jar file to download and use ?**

Second question: I did not see exact example that I might use or would be very similar to my case. **Someone to point me the right direction ( or prove i am blind ) ?** Example of video streaming from android to android ( server-client ) would be mostly appreciated.

PS: Xuggle seemed like the best option here, but I am opened if there is a better solution, preferably with a sample similar to my use-case :)

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Did you manage to use xuggle and send video via RTP`?